# Default parameter for a list reference

Tags: c++, default

In C++, how would I specify a default value for a list reference in a function?

```
void fun(
  std::list<My_Object *> &the_list,
  int n = 4
)
```

Comment: What should the default value be?

Comment: A specific list. I'd prefer to enter it in-line. (Thanks for fixing the mark-up.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if it is a plain reference, the only thing you an default it to is a valid lvalue which probably is not available. But if it is a reference to const you could default it to an empty list like this:

```
void fun(
  std::list<My_Object *> const & the_list = std::list<My_Object *>(),
  int n = 4
)
```

If you have a list named a, which is available at the declaration site, then like this

```
void fun(
      std::list<My_Object *> & the_list = a,
      int n = 4
    )
```

but be careful so that the `a` list is still "alive" when you call the function

Answer (score 5):

> In C++, how would I specify a default
>   value for a list reference in a
>   function?

I wouldn't, in your case. Either ***overload the function*** so that it can be called without a list, or ***take the argument per pointer***, so that users can pass a `NULL` pointer.

I'd strongly prefer overloading.

Comment: The function in question is a constructor of ~16 lines, and so overloading would lead to some duplicate code.

Comment: You can factor out common initialization logic, or construct a new one with an lvalue and then swap.

Comment: @Tim: Yes, unfortunately C++03 doesn't allow direct constructor forwarding

Comment: @Tim: I think C++1x will allow constructor forwarding. Your compiler might already support that. Otherwise DeadMG's swapping idea might be the best shot at this.